# Camera calibration in OpenCV - findCirclesGrid centres are very inaccurate

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I'm using OpenCV in Python to calibrate a DSLR camera and 50 mm lens, using the asymmetric circles pattern. This pattern is occasionally recommended as being superior to the chessboard, so I'm trying  to compare result of the two.

I can find the circles correctly in images taken at various distances. Running batches of 10-20 images I consistently get reprojection errors of 0.8-1.0. It is clear from the image below that the centres which are returned are not very accurate. Is there any way to improve these results?

[image: Asymmetric Circles]

I have tried tweaking the SimpleBlobDetector_Params, but there doesn't seem to be any way to control how it calculates the centers of the blobs it finds.

Comment: if your lighting is consistent, just threshold, then connected components with stats. -- circles are inferior because the 2d geometric center of a projected circle (which is an ellipse) is NOT EQUAL TO the projection of the 3D center of that circle. if anyone claimed otherwise, please report them to the authorities.

Comment: What Christoph says, as far as OpenCv calibrateCamera is concerned. It is theoretically possible to use a circles pattern to calibrate with higher accuracy than with a simple point-based checkerboard, but to do so one must bundle adjust on several points on the detected boundaries of the circles' images. In other words, one must fit a model of the circles that predicts image locations on their boundaries, rather than their centers, because the boundaries are observable, and the centers ain't.

Comment: (I don't know the detail, but) it seems something related for this problem(Modification for circular control points) is indicated in `Kannala et al. , "A Generic Camera Calibration Method for Fish-Eye Lenses"`